# QGraphicsTextItem appears blurry after it gets scaled in size

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a class that adds a label for another QGraphicsWidget
in my QGraphicsScene. The zoom is set by the scale factor;
after I scale it, it gets blurry.

This is what it looks like without scaling:

[image]

This is what it looks like normally:

[image: When changing scale, the image becomes blurry]

In my QGraphicsView, I have set the render hints as:

```
self.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter.TextAntialiasing)
```

This only seems to affect painted items.

Here is my code:

```
class Label(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, node):
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.install = "label"
        self.node = node
        self.textItem = QGraphicsTextItem(self)

        font = self.textItem.font() #type: QFont
        font.setStyleStrategy(QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.textItem.setFont(font)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, False)

        self.set()

        self.node.nameChanged.connect(self.set)

    def set(self):
        # print "setting: {}".format(self.node.name)
        self.textItem.setPlainText(self.node.name)
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.setPreferredSize(
        QSizeF(self.textItem.boundingRect().width(), self.textItem.boundingRect().height())
    )

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.textItem.boundingRect()
```

Comment: what is node in your class?

Comment: @eyllanesc its another QGraphicsWidget that adds the Label to its layout

Comment: It would be good if you display a replicable code

Comment: Your code does not recreate what you show, please show the necessary code

Comment: if i were to add just the widget to the scene it would do the same thing.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem but it is impossible to do with the code that you show